# Set a typedef with default generic types

Tags: dart

I have some generic values used many times on my code. Can I create a type setting a default values for these generics?

Something like:

```
typedef MapStringInt = Map<String, int>; // it won't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typedefs are only for defining function type aliases. You can follow this GitHub issue which are about adding typedef for non-function types:

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65